# Powering ESP32-WROOM-32E using LM1117S-3.3 LDO voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, esp32, ldo

I want to power my ESP32-WROOM-32E module with an 3.7V Li-Po battery. To reduce the voltage to 3.3V I'd like to use **LM1117S-3.3** LDO. As far as I know, the most ESP32 developing boards use **AM1117** regulator. Is there any differences between **AM1117** and **LM1117**? Is it possible to use **LM1117**?

Comment: It's not possible to use either of them due to their >= 1 V dropout voltage, it is more than 3.7 - 3.3.

Comment: You probably mean AMS1117. Details like that are rather important many times. In this case, the answer is 'no' in both cases. They're not really LDOs,  more like medium dropout regulators.

Comment: The LM1117 is generally going to be much more reliable than the AMS1117; the latter is a cost-reduced knockoff known for having issues (though I can't recall exactly what issues right now. Something with oscillation?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From:  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf

To generate 3.3V you must provide a battery that is at least 1.3V higher, so this will work as long as your battery is 4.6V or higher.  A 3.7V battery will not work.

Depending on how much you care about battery life, a buck-boost converter might make more sense than a linear regulator.  It will waste less power and allow you to run the battery to a lower voltage before dropping out.

Comment: Will one of this [buck-boost converters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206023/is-it-safe-to-use-esp8266-with-3-7v) work. Which is the best to use in my case?

Comment: @AntonTsvayer Yes those look like reasonable choices. I would double check that they can safely handle a dead battery without discharging it below 3v, but otherwise should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the battery charging management I will use another circuit.